# Combine Column and Line Chart Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am looking to create a 2 column chart that has a horizontal "goal" line across it.  I am really just unsure how the dataset needs to look in order to achieve this.  I really don't know what the use for the Category and Series group, or if I even need them.  What I have is two columns that are based on inflation, so i could use the inflation rate as the X-Axis values usually between 0 and 10 except the horizontal goal line does not relate to these inflation percentages at all, they are just a static whole number value I want to display a straight line for on top of my two columns.  This is what it should look like;

[image]

The "Assumed Returns" are the inflation values, with the $ value on the Y-Axis and the 'BasicGoal' as the orange line.  I have the columns rendering perfectly, but can not get the orange line for the BasicGoal to save my life, i have tried stripLines, but they render behind the data and don't help me at all in this case, and have also gotten individual data-points to render the value of the orange line in the label, but i can't render it straight across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the goal line as an extra column in your dataset, and then adding it to the graph as a line series?

I'm assuming your dataset looks like this, with the addition of a Goal column:

```
 Assumed Returns   Linear Returns   Goal
 ---------------   --------------   ---------
 0.0               45,243           40,000
 0.5               48,869           40,000
```

Add a new series to the chart based on the Goal column and then change it's series type to line.

Comment: I actually just created a new dataset with that exact type of setup with the Goal being included in each line of data.  I am now just working on getting it to stretch the full width of the x-axis values, thank you for your suggestion, could not figure out the proper way to approach this! marked as correct

Comment: To make the goal line stretch the entire x-axis, simply add some fictive rows to the dataset, outside the relevant x-axis interval: For example, `Assumed Returns = -0.5, Linear Returns = NULL, Goal = 40000` and `Assumed Returns = 1.0, Linear Returns = NULL, Goal = 40000`. Then, manually limit your x-axis to only show data between, say, 0.25 and 0.75.